# SBT Error: "Failed to construct terminal; falling back to unsupported..."

Tags: sbt

I have run into an ERROR with SBT today. It can best be shown with the `sbt sbt-version` command:

Run on 5/29/17:

```
eric@linux-x2vq:~$ sbt sbt-version
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option 
MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Set current project to eric (in build file:/home/eric/)
[info] 0.13.13
```

Run on 6/1/17:

```
eric@linux-x2vq:~$ sbt sbt-version
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option             
MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
[ERROR] Failed to construct terminal; falling back to unsupported
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0x100"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
at jline.internal.InfoCmp.parseInfoCmp(InfoCmp.java:59)
at jline.UnixTerminal.parseInfoCmp(UnixTerminal.java:233)
at jline.UnixTerminal.<init>(UnixTerminal.java:64)
at jline.UnixTerminal.<init>(UnixTerminal.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at jline.TerminalFactory.getFlavor(TerminalFactory.java:209)
at jline.TerminalFactory.create(TerminalFactory.java:100)
at jline.TerminalFactory.get(TerminalFactory.java:184)
at jline.TerminalFactory.get(TerminalFactory.java:190)
at sbt.ConsoleLogger$.ansiSupported(ConsoleLogger.scala:123)
at sbt.ConsoleLogger$.<init>(ConsoleLogger.scala:117)
at sbt.ConsoleLogger$.<clinit>(ConsoleLogger.scala)
at sbt.GlobalLogging$.initial(GlobalLogging.scala:43)
at sbt.StandardMain$.initialGlobalLogging(Main.scala:64)
at sbt.StandardMain$.initialState(Main.scala:73)
at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:29)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)

[info] Set current project to eric (in build file:/home/eric/)
[info] 0.13.13
```

No changes (that I know of) to either my SBT or Java setup.

Any ideas on what might be causing this or how to fix the error?

Thank you!

Comment: I have the same issue. The problem is, that `infocmp` has a hex value for `color#0x100` which jline.UnixTerminal cannot parse. The bug was already fixed: https://github.com/jline/jline2/commit/c1b1676de1803278289af0622ad202f1c7a526ec

Comment: In my case simply upgrading SBT to the latest version did it.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I found the package which causes this issue: `ncurses`. I downgraded `ncurses` to version `ncurses-6.0+20170429-1` (I am using Arch Linux) and SBT starts just fine.

Steps for Arch Linux:

```
cd /var/cache/pacman/pkg
sudo pacman -U ncurses-6.0+20170429-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz # or some other older version
```

Steps for Mac: see https://github.com/jline/jline2/issues/281

I think this issue was introduced with ncurses version 20170506, see: http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#index-t20170506

```
+ modify tic/infocmp display of numeric values to use hexadecimal when
      they are "close" to a power of two, making the result more readable.
```

I filed an issue on the SBT issue tracker: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3240

**Edit:** SBT version 0.13.16 includes the fix for this problem.

Comment: Thank you for this and your post to github. I noticed the problem immediately after an openSUSE Tumbleweed update yesterday. ncurses! I will watch for developments. Appreciated. :-)

Comment: how could I do that on Ubuntu?

Comment: The correct way to actually fix all this is upgrade scala from 2.11.X to 2.13.X. See: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3240#issuecomment-325899575

The guilty lib is `jline`. :D

Answer (score 192):

I had the same issue, especially when the `TERM` environment variable is set to `xterm-256color`. Setting it to a different value fixed the issue for me, e.g.

```
export TERM=xterm-color
```

Comment: works for me, arch user. Arch Kernel 4.11.3-1-ARCH, sbt version 2.5.15 "Streamy"

Comment: added this at the top of my sbt launcher

Comment: Also works for me, Arch Linux. Added that line to my ~/.bashrc file.

Comment: Works for Macos. I use zsh as my shell.

Comment: man I have no idea how that works but it did fix my problem as well. I'm running Arch Kernel 4.16.3-1-ARCH, jline 2.14.2

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I put this in `~/.bashrc` :)

Comment: started getting this in sbt 1.2.0, setting `export TERM=xterm-color` also fixed this for me

Comment: Fedora 28 here: That's it, should be the accepted answer since I don't want to downgrade my libs. Why doesnt SBT catch this error!

Answer (score 25):

You can add `export TERM=xterm-color` to the top of `/usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt` because `$HOME/.sbtconfig` is deprecated.

Comment: The file `/usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt` is very likely to be installed as part of the `sbt` package by a package manager. Any edits to this file might be removed upon the `sbt` package being updated, which could be either invisible to a particular user (if some other person is updating the `sbt` package) or overwritten in a moment of forgetfulness.

Comment: Well that would be good because it's apparently fixed in later versions.

Answer (score 22):

`sbt` command is just a script. It load `$HOME/.sbtconfig` at the very beginning, so just put

```
export TERM=xterm-color
```

as @user3113045 said in the conf file, sbt will work. In that case your other term commands will still use `xterm-256color`.

Comment: I put `export TERM=xterm-color` in my `~/.bashrc` and it works fine.

Comment: First, use `which sbt` to find the folder that needs to put the line in.E.g., mine is`/usr/local/opt/sbt@0.13/bin/sbt`. I put the line in it and it worked

Answer (score 9):

This resolved the issue in my case (Linux Users):

1. Open your terminal
2. Navigate to your project directory
3. type "export TERM=xterm-color" in your terminal without the quotes
4. Hit ENTER

That is all and then you are good to go.

Comment: I put the statement in my .bashrc (Ubuntu). Worked perfect. I assume it will work for me in Fedora as well.

Comment: Worked for me on an ec2 instance in a cluster. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

One year passed... now it happened to me.

---

So, **ncurses** did change, and the corresponding **sbt** part was ...I guess... probably only implemented based on random guessed tests and observations/bugs and not any spec nor RFC. (So far, sbt is the only program with this ncurses issue that I know of.)

In case you can't simply **upgrade sbt** nor **downgrade ncurses**, you could change the TERM environment variable as mentioned in the other answers.

### trivial fix:

If your sbt script is some bash script (most likely, unless you run DOS' .bat files)

```
$ file /usr/bin/sbt
/usr/bin/sbt: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

, then it might suffice to add this workaround:

```
TERM="${TERM/xterm-256color/xterm-color}"
```

Comment: Rather than `file /usr/bin/sbt`, you might want to use `file -L \`which sbt\`` to make sure that the sbt that is on the user's path is checked and that any symbolic links are followed.

Comment: indeed. you could also add another script as wrapper and put that in PATH shadowing the original.

Answer (score 3):

If you can, change sbt version in build.properties to higher. 13.16 work for me.

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu 20.04 Users, Open your terminal and run the bellow CMDs

- Go to this "/usr/share/sbt/bin" directory ( $ cd /usr/share/sbt/bin )
- give the permission to edit file ( $ sudo chmod -R 777 sbt )
- Open the **sbt** text file in this directory ( $ nano sbt )
- Add this "export TERM=xterm-color" cmd in top and save ( Ctrl + X )

Ex:-

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export TERM=xterm-color
set +e
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't write a comment as my score is too low, but user3113045's answer worked when I added `export TERM=xterm-color` to my `.zshrc` file

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when i am using activator which uses sbt internally.
I am using Ubuntu and this error was frustrating me.
I started facing this issue when i ran

$ activator gen-idea (tool which as per the intellij is legacy)

After this i tried to delete all the cache that this tool generated.

I deleted the .ivy and .sbt directories from my home folder and ran the activator cleanFiles compile command which resolved my issue.