# sbt crashes on attempt to run after installation

Tags: sbt

In order to solve [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788781/ubuntu-scala-repl-commands-not-typed-on-console), I tried to install sbt using the following commands:

```
echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sbt
```

When I then type `sbt`, I get this output:

```
[warn] No sbt.version set in project/build.properties, base directory: /usr/share
[error] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Source file '/usr/share/icons/Humanity/status@2/48/aptdaemon-update-cache.svg' does not exist.
[error]     at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:277)
[error]     at sbt.io.IO$.copyFile(IO.scala:823)
[error]     at sbt.io.IO$.copyImpl(IO.scala:766)
[error]     at sbt.io.IO$.$anonfun$copy$1(IO.scala:754)
[error]     at scala.Function$.$anonfun$tupled$1(Function.scala:77)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:233)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:58)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:51)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:226)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
[error]     at sbt.io.IO$.copy(IO.scala:754)
[error]     at sbt.io.IO$.copyDirectory(IO.scala:800)
[error]     at sbt.io.IO$.copyDirectory(IO.scala:789)
[error]     at sbt.io.IO$.copyDirectory(IO.scala:772)
[error]     at sbt.Resolvers$.$anonfun$local$3(Resolvers.scala:34)
[error]     at sbt.Resolvers$.creates(Resolvers.scala:148)
[error]     at sbt.Resolvers$.$anonfun$local$2(Resolvers.scala:34)
[error]     at sbt.internal.BuildLoader$.$anonfun$componentLoader$2(BuildLoader.scala:172)
[error]     at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
[error]     at sbt.internal.BuildLoader$.$anonfun$componentLoader$1(BuildLoader.scala:171)
[error]     at sbt.internal.MultiHandler.apply(BuildLoader.scala:28)
[error]     at sbt.internal.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:240)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.loadURI$1(Load.scala:546)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:562)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:492)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.load(Load.scala:471)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$apply$1(Load.scala:251)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1395)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.apply(Load.scala:251)
[error]     at sbt.internal.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:69)
[error]     at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.liftedTree1$1(Main.scala:829)
[error]     at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:829)
[error]     at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2(Main.scala:800)
[error]     at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$4(Command.scala:142)
[error]     at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$2(Command.scala:137)
[error]     at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:181)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.processCommand(MainLoop.scala:151)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$2(MainLoop.scala:139)
[error]     at sbt.State$$anon$1.runCmd$1(State.scala:246)
[error]     at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:250)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$1(MainLoop.scala:139)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:139)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:132)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1(MainLoop.scala:110)
[error]     at sbt.io.Using.apply(Using.scala:22)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:104)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:59)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:35)
[error]     at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:138)
[error]     at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:89)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:56)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:18)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Source file '/usr/share/icons/Humanity/status@2/48/aptdaemon-update-cache.svg' does not exist.
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? i
[warn] Ignoring load failure: no project loaded.
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Session not initialized.
[error]     at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
[error]     at sbt.Project$.$anonfun$getOrError$1(Project.scala:442)
[error]     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
[error]     at sbt.Project$.getOrError(Project.scala:442)
[error]     at sbt.Project$.session(Project.scala:448)
[error]     at sbt.Project$.extract(Project.scala:453)
[error]     at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.notifyUsersAboutShell(Main.scala:928)
[error]     at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.$anonfun$notifyUsersAboutShell$3(Main.scala:937)
[error]     at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$command$2(Command.scala:91)
[error]     at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:181)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.processCommand(MainLoop.scala:151)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$2(MainLoop.scala:139)
[error]     at sbt.State$$anon$1.runCmd$1(State.scala:246)
[error]     at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:250)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$1(MainLoop.scala:139)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:139)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:132)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1(MainLoop.scala:110)
[error]     at sbt.io.Using.apply(Using.scala:22)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:104)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:59)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:35)
[error]     at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:138)
[error]     at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:89)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:56)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:18)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] Session not initialized.
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

What is the problem here? I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.2.

Answer (score 0):

```
[warn] No sbt.version set in project/build.properties, base directory: /usr/share
```

Did you try to run `sbt` in `/usr/share`?
If so please try running it in a working directory where you have write rights. For a quick start see [sbt by example](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-by-example.html).